# Begin a storyboard when hovering an Image

Tags: wpf, image, triggers, storyboard

I have a simple image on my form. What I would like to do is when I hover the image it starts a storyboard which basically does a 360 loop on itself.
Here's the storyboard, it's called TurnLogo:

```
  <Storyboard x:Key="TurnLogo">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Here's my image :

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Source="Images/Logo/Logomakr_3lb9fd.png" Margin="7,7,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseEnter">
                           <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TurnLogo}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

When I hover the image it fails.. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Storyboard.TargetName`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="TurnLogo">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                     By="360" Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

and simplify the RenderTransform:

```
<Image ... RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                   <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TurnLogo}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```